# My iOS plugin for phonegap app worked once. When app is started again it doesn't work until I go background and return to app

Tags: ios, iphone, plugins, cordova

I have iPhone app made with PhoneGap 2.8.1 and I've recently faced strange problem:
I've written plugin that store some app secrets on device, hashes given data (using those secrets) and return this hash to JS.

When I run my app for the first time after installation everything work just fine.
But when I start it again app freezes just before (or maybe on) start of my plugin method.
3rd party plugins loaded before start ok, but when it comes to my plugin - nothing is happening.

Nothing on Xcode console, nothing on weinre console. Null. No error exceptions, no logs from native code.
When I try to run some native methods manually from weinre console nothing happens too.

But when I turn my app background by hitting home button and return to it, everything is magically starting to work!

Does anyone have similar problem? Any solutions? Clues?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the plugin after "deviceready" is fired ?

Comment: Yes, my whole app starts after deviceready event is fired.

Comment: Could you please show some code ? like how are you using your plugin ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm facing a similar problem, but with Phonegap's Media and Dialogs plugins, and I can't find anything about this online.

Comment: Oh yes, it turned out that I had error in JS (using non existing method). And that error blocked everything. So check your JS!

Answer (score 0):

I have method that hashes data which will be send in request to my API. I use it like this:

```
window.plugins.protocol.hamac data, (results) =>
    # work with results
```

Native code looks like this:

```
- (void)hamac:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    NSLog(@"HAMAC STARTED!");
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;

    @try {
        NSDictionary* data = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

        if (data != nil) {
            // prepare string to be hashed

            pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsDictionary: @{
                                                                                                        @"status": @YES,
                                                                                                        @"h": [self sha1:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stringToHash]
                                                                                                        }];
        } else {
            pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsDictionary: @{
                                                                                                           @"status": @NO,
                                                                                                           @"error": @"No data!"
                                                                                                           }];
        }
    } @catch (NSException* e) {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsDictionary: @{
                                                                                                       @"status": @NO,
                                                                                                       @"error": @"Failed to hash data"
                                                                                                       }];
    }

    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}
```